# downloading data from GCE VM instance to a local PC - is it egress data?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Is downloading the data from the GCE VM instance to a local PC also considered an egress network data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/network-pricing) says that data leaving a Google resource is indeed part of egress data.